# Storing Formatted Data in C

Tags: c

Im trying to add variables to a C char array.  Also I have tried `sprintf`, but it is causing a few other issues within my program.

I am looking to do something like this:

```
char* age = "My age is = " + age;
```

I am planning on sending the char array to a socket using `send()`

Answer (score 3):

s(n)printf is really the right answer here.  What issues is it causing?  Try and fix those issues vs. throwing the right tool away.

Comment: Sorry, oversimplified.  Yes, unless you KNOW your formatting vs. buffer size, then yes, snprintf is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++ then just use std::string to get this functionality ...

Under C you just can't do it using operator overloads.  "strcat" allows you to concatenate 2 strange. Just make sure you have space to store the resulting string!

Answer (score 0):

Use `sprintf()`. Remember to allocate a large enough buffer for the array. Like this:

```
char buf[24];
sprintf(buf, "My age is = %d", age);
```

24 `char`s are long enough to contain the result here, whatever the value of `age` is. I'm assuming that `age` is a 32-bit integer.

Of course, if you change the text to something longer, you will have to increase the size of the buffer.